# Checking CSOM people editor value

Tags: 2013, jquery, client-object-model, people-picker

How can we check the  user entered key in Client people editor is user or group? I have created a people editor in CSOM. I can save the value to the list successfully. But before saving i need to check whether the entered key is User or Group? Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be an object on the page named `SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict`. It holds information about all your people pickers on page. The ID of your pickers is the property name in the object. So to check type, you could use the following:

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["IDofYourPicker"].GetAllUserInfo()[0].EntityType
```

That will give you blank for SharePoint Group, User for Users and SecGroup for AD-sec group. And you could check the EntityData for information about the groups/ppl